# In Android, why is Facebook signup not working if Facebook installed in the device already?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, fbconnect

I have tried to use Facebook in my application, this works fine on device that doesn't have Facebook app installed. But this fails to give the session while there is Facebook already installed on the device.

```
public void facebookSignIn(CallbackContext callContext){
    try {
        isFacebookLogin = true;
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();               }
        });
        this.callbackContext = callContext;
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Log.d("facebook","session open");
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                String userID = user.getId();
                                callbackContext.success(userID);
                                Toast.makeText(MDLIVEMain.this, user.getName() + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                callbackContext.error(MDLiveLocalizationSystem.localizedStringForKey("nat_authen_failure"));
                            }
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }).executeAsync();
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error(MDLiveLocalizationSystem.localizedStringForKey("nat_authen_failure"));
        GATrackingExceptions.trackExceptions(e.getLocalizedMessage(), MDLIVEMain.this);
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is onactivityResult code

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    try {
        CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallbacks;
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        }
        Log.d("isFacebookLogin",isFacebookLogin+"");
        if(isFacebookLogin){
            try {
                isFacebookLogin = false;
                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, responseCode, intent);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (requestCode == PASSCODE_RESULT_PAGE) {
                if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    activityVisible = true;
                    this.callbackContext.success(intent.getExtras().getString("passcode_pin"));
                } else {
                    this.callbackContext.success(intent.getExtras().getString("passcode_pin"));
                    isFromPasscodePage = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to make a valid Hash, the only reason is Hash value.

Comment: But this works if there is no facebook installed in device.

Comment: use following procedure & every thing will work perfect.. Even in the presence of Facebook installed. I too faced this type of issue but then found a solution in the procedure I  have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered for this type of (Hash for fb) issue here :

[Facebook Login and Post To Wall works for first time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356984/facebook-login-and-post-to-wall-works-for-first-time-only/25357104#25357104)

Note: Fb gives issues bcz of not valid Hash, for that you have to generate a valid hash.

Comment: if it works for you, plz do mark so others can also get rid of this issue.

Comment: Before Session.isOpen() this reach to isClose() function. so i am not able to get the user details . May i know why this happening

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore C:/Users/sampath_k/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | o
penssl base64
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Am not able to that steps. Plz can you give me the exact steps and requirement for openssl as well

Comment: I guess you are not following it correctly, take a close look at commands.

Comment: Yes i too think. but am not able to get what needs to be done because it says "'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: you have to download it, sorry i forget to mentioned that

Comment: use my updated answer, now it will not give you error.